# MYSQL How to "Join" two Queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one containing the UID of users with a FID (File ID) and one table containg the FID with their URI. I need to get the URI with just the UID.

My first though is to first load all of the FID with a Query and then use the fetched data to make an other query that will load the URI in the second table according to the fetched FIDs.

Since this query is going to be run a lot on this site i was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do so ? Would it be possible to join those 2 queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a simple join like this:

```
SELECT uid, uri FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.fid = table2.fid
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick reply, but what if i know the UID of my user and i want to get it s URI? Where in that query can i specify that UID ?

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that in your question. Try this: `SELECT uri FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.fid = table2.fid AND table1.uid = YOUR_SPECIFIC_UID`

Comment: Yes it does work, thanks again, sorry for the delay i was making further testing to be sure i had the right solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      U.UID,
      F.FID,
      F.URI 
FROM users_Table AS U
JOIN files_Table AS F
  ON U.FID = F.FID
WHERE U.UID = "user_identification_number"
```

Comment: thanks, though i don t understand why to select  the FID, would this work as well ? 
`select 
  F.URI 
from users as U
 join files as F
  on U.FID = F.FID`

Comment: yes, it will work. It was just an example how to get userID, fileID and fileURI with one query. You may add more field if you need or remove unnecessary right after `select` statement

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correct this could be solved with a simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT UID, URI
FROM `table1` as t1, `table2` as t2
WHERE t1.FID = t2.FID;
```

Read more about how joins work at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy for SQL join.

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.`uri`
FROM `users` t1
JOIN `files` t2 ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`uid`
```